# From Excel to CSV (one single column)

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter

I am trying to convert an excel to a csv but with the columns in the excel merged into one in the csv, as shown in the screenshot. See [image]

I have tried to do it by saving the excel document into a csv separated by commas but the columns are still kept. See [image]. The format is a csv though.

Error detected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MkW0.png)

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand your pictures

If you save as csv and open it in notepad, you will see the comma

Excel seems to show it in columns

[image]

In case you just want one column and not really a csv you can do it with a formula

```
=A1&","&B1
```

[image]

Comment: The problem that R detects is the following: Your file must not have decimal points/separators and ideally has no spaces (for the latter, use '_' instead)!
Also, don't forget that R's treatment of alphanumeric characters is case-sensitive!


Load the tab-delimited input file:
Press <Enter> to continue ...

Comment: The error image is included above.